# Lie algebras of the unit group of a finite dimensional algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given a finite dimmensional associative algebra $A$, it can be proven that the unit group $$A^{\ast}:=\{a\in A \mid \exists\, b \in A \mbox{ such that } ab=ba=1_A\} $$  is always a Lie group ([The unit group of a finite dimensional associative algebra is a Lie group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2801717/the-unit-group-of-a-finite-dimensional-associative-algebra-is-a-lie-group)), but I have problems trying to identify its Lie algebra. I think that its Lie algebra $(\mathfrak{a},[.,.])$ should be isomorphic (as Lie algebras) to $(A,[.,.]_c)$, where $[a,b]_c=ab-ba$ (as the case $A=M_n(\mathbb{K})$). It is true?? I hope somebody can help me

Comment: You should add the assumption of the linked question and answer that $\Bbb K$ is a complete valued field (as otherwise the concept of "Lie group" makes little sense to begin with).

Comment: Well, of course $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R} $ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Of course ... (Many people are investigating $p$-adic Lie groups, but of course that need not be your business.) Your conjecture sounds plausible, but what have you tried? And what construction of the Lie algebra of a Lie group are you using in this generality -- invariant vector fields, tangent space, invariant derivations ...?

Comment: I have tried considering $\mathfrak{a}$ as tangent space but the problem is choose a basis on $A$ (based in the case $A=M_n(\mathbb{K}$)).